# Answering phone during Kerias Shema

Tags: halacha, technology, shema

There are various rules pertaining to interruptions during the recitation of Shema. As first formulated in the Mishnah ([Berachos 13a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=13&format=pdf)), there are certain interruptions that are allowed for "honor" and for "fear" or for "anyone".

> בפרקים שואל מפני הכבוד ומשיב ובאמצע שואל מפני היראה ומשיב דברי ר' מאיר
>   ר' יהודה אומר באמצע שואל מפני היראה ומשיב מפני הכבוד ובפרקים שואל מפני
>   הכבוד ומשיב שלום לכל אדם
>
> IN THE BREAKS ONE MAY GIVE GREETING OUT OF RESPECT AND RETURN
>   GREETING; IN THE MIDDLE [OF A SECTION] ONE MAY GIVE GREETING OUT OF
>   FEAR AND RETURN IT. SO R. MEIR. RABBI JUDAH SAYS: IN THE MIDDLE ONE
>   MAY GIVE GREETING OUT OF FEAR AND RETURN IT OUT OF RESPECT, IN THE
>   BREAKS ONE MAY GIVE GREETING OUT OF RESPECT AND RETURN GREETING TO
>   ANYONE. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

How do these laws apply to modern technology? For example, if someone in one of the categories calls you at a point that would be permissible to respond in person, can you answer your phone just like you could answer him in person? Or does the dispensation to interrupt Shema only apply when the person is physically in front of you and talks to you?

Is this discussed in any Rabbinic Literature?

(I am aware that a bunch of Acharonim cite the Sefer Hachinuch that the whole dispensation doesn't really apply nowadays even in person. My question is assuming not like this, so I would not consider this an answer. And even if someone would show that this is the unanimous consensus, it still wouldn't address the underlying theory of the question.)

Comment: Ideally, you should have your phone off during services in synagogue, as not only is it a distraction to you, but it also is a big distraction for others who are trying to daven.

Comment: From logic, the reason to answer when these people are before you is because it is disrespectful to not answer someone talking to you.  That seemingly doesn't apply to phone calls nowadays. If my mother calls me and I am busy, I don't necessarily answer but call her back.

Comment: @zeev maybe you're indeed being disrespectful to your mother

Comment: @ezra There are companies that encourage shuls to install phone lockers!

Comment: I think *Hatzalah* members are allowed to answer their phones not just during *Shema*, but during *Amidah* as well as every call may be *piku'ach nefesh*.

Comment: @DanF I think that's the best idea ever! Court houses have lockers for people's phones (and other items). All the more so should a shul!

Comment: @ezra See http://www.thelakewoodscoop.com/news/2013/02/photos-first-ever-cell-phone-lockers-come-to-a-lakewood-shul.html. Lakewood may have been a "leader", but others have followed, apparently. There are some drawbacks, though - No using the Smart Phone siddur anymore and people will talk more in shul, now. With the smart phone, they were texting during davening, so the shul was actually quieter. That last item sounds weird, I know, but, I think it's something shuls need to consider before enforcing the locker rule.

Comment: @DanF I hate phone siddurim. I'd rather have people control themselves

Answer (score 2):

This case discussed exactly by Rav Dov Lior [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/19740), and the exact answer that you didn't want to be given is given, along with one other tiny consideration that one can likely finish until Bein Haperakim and therefore should do that.  This last point technically answers the question asked about rabbinic literature, but not your **real** question about how this applies to modern technology.

(By the way, you could probably suggest an answer based on the Sevaros that Rishonim give for these halachos, but I understand that you are looking for others who have already done that.)

Here's the full text:

> שאלה:
>   האם באמצע קריאת שמע וברכותיה, יהיה מותר לענות לפלאפון שרטט (אם בטעות לא כיביתי לפני התפילה), כשאני רואה שהשיחה היא מההורים מדין "שואלים מפני הכבוד ומשיבין מפני היראה"?‏
>
> תשובה:
>   בזמננו לא נהגו לענות מפני הכבוד, משום שכולם יודעים שאדם עומד בתפילה ואינו יכול לדבר. אם זה לא ספק פיקוח נפש, אל תענה לשיחת הטלפון בכלל. **ואם יש חשש שזה משהו מאוד דחוף, תענה בין הפרקים.**‏

---

A quick note about that Chinuch/our Minhag - it is certainly not universal, see Tzitz Eliezer 2:1:3 about how it may be an obligation to respond nowadays, and perhaps even according to the Chinuch:

> ואף שהחינוך (במצוה ת"כ) הובא במג"א (ריש סי' ס"ו) כתב, דכמה שלא ראינו מי שיקפיד על חבירו כלל אם לא יפסיק לו לא יפסוק ואפי' בין הפרקים מלבד מה שי"ל שאף החינוך לא אמר כן כ"א בשאר כל אדם שאינו מחויב לכבדם אבל לא באביו ורבו שמחויב ומצווה מה"ת לכבדם ואין תלוי ביקפיד או לא יקפיד, ובפרט כשהם מקדימים לו שלום שזו הוכחה שרצונם שיענה להם, מלבד זה הרמב"ם בפסקיו (בפ"ב מה' ק"ש הט"ו) אינו מבדיל בכלל בין מקפיד או לא מקפיד, ומלשונו הפסקנית בחיוב ההפסקה משמע שמחויב להפסיק בלי כל תנאים, וז"ל: היה קורא ופגע באחרים או פגעו בו אחרים אם היה בין פרק לפרק פוסק ומתחיל ושואל שלום מי שהוא חייב בכבודו כגון שפגע באביו או ברבו או מי שהוא גדול ממנו בחכמה, ומשיב שלום לכל אדם שנתן לו שלום, הרי שפסקיה בסכינא חריפא שפוסק ומתחיל ושואל שלום, וכן להלן בה' ט"ז בהיה קורא באמצע הפרשה, פוסק, שאם מי שהוא חייב לכבדו כגון אביו או רבו נתן לו שלום תחילה פוסק ומשיב לו שלום.  ‏
>
> וא"כ י"ל שכוונת הרמב"ם בפיה"מ שכותב ופי' לחתום רוצה לומר שיפסוק במקום שאינו ראוי לפסוק הוא שאף שהמקום אינו ראוי בדרך כלל לפסוק, בכל זאת בגוונא שחז"ל אמרו לחתום ולפסוק, אינו רשאי להחמיר על עצמו שלא לחתום ולא להפסיק, כי אם מחויב לחתום ולהפסיק, ובגוונא שאמרו שלא לחתום ולא להפסיק, אזי אינו רשאי לחתום ולהפסיק. ‏

---

Apologies if you personally dislike the answer, but I felt it contributed too much to not be posted, even if it might not answer the question the way you want it to.

Comment: It's definitely useful (upvote). But what I really would like is a discussion of whether the concept of "honor" or "fear" is applicable to a phone call. (Such a discussion could be via citing those who have written about this, or by constructing one's own argument.)

Comment: משום שכולם יודעים שאדם עומד בתפילה ואינו יכול לדבר but that's not true when they try to call you on the phone because they don't see you

Comment: @Heshy I had the same issue.  He seems to be saying that the whole concept is batel nowadays.